# Scrollable fragment in ConstraintLayout - Android

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I would like to create an app with a layout like this
[image: this]

There are three fragments with some of views. Unfortunately, I can't scroll up or down in the fragments of the viewpager. For example, I can't scroll the text in this fragment

[image: in this fragment]

Here is the code of my layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimary" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scrim_gradient"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/whiteGreyish"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_challenge_cover_image"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/iv_2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_cover"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/iv_2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/iv_1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_1"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/whiteGreyish"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_upload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```